# Java Arab UTF-8 encoding not the same as Notepad++ UTF-8 encoding

Tags: java, utf-8, notepad++, arabic, inputstreamreader

I am currently writining a program, that is supposed to read arab lines from xml/properties files and display it in a JTable. 
Thats my InputStreamReader:

```
new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(f), "UTF-8");
```

My problem is, that for example this حذف المسار line looks like this حذ�? المسار in my JTable and i dont know why.

Thanks for a solution in advance.

SOLUTION: Changed encoding of JLables in JTable to UTF-8 using `this.setText(new String(someString.getBytes("UTF-8")));`

Comment: The cause of a character encoding bug can be in many places, for example in where you read or write the text, or where you display the text. You'll have to carefully debug your application to find out where it goes wrong. Without knowing any more details about your software it's impossible to tell from your question where the bug is.

Comment: Well, the only lines where i specify the encoding is InputStreamReader and OutputStream reader. Everything else is set to default (JTable, TableModel, TableRenderer). The files i use are UTF-8 encoded.